# Is there a standard way to keep modified Linux configuration files separate and identifiable?

Tags: linux, configuration, admin, symlink

Often I need to edit many configuration files under `/etc`, however, I don't want these changes to get lost when I'll perform my next system upgrade.

Right now, I've housed all configuration files as well as some of my maintenance scripts in  `/opt/admin`, and symlinked `/etc` targets there, but that doesn't seem right [according to standards I've seen](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html). Another option I thought of, is housing these in `/usr/local`. The aforementioned document says it is *for use by the system administrator when installing software locally*. That's the closest I've got. However, also `/usr/local` gets clobbered when you install new non-packaged software.

Is there a standard/largely followed best-practice as to how to maintain these? 
Since this is not a discussion page, answers should be definite and with an article or two to support them.

**EDIT**

Since this was rightfully put *on hold* I thought I'd redirect you to a [similar question in Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/348033/standard-configuration-of-a-webservers-filesystem).

There seem to be two general solutions - either use symlinks or maintain a list of files (see ptman's answer in linked question).

For now, I'm using a hybrid solution: maintain a list of configuration files (`/opt/admin/config/FILES`). A script (`/opt/admin/scripts/link-config-files.sh`) creates a symlinked hierarchy (under `/opt/admin/config`). Files are now easily accessible from one place, where it's clear where they're really located, there's a central list of files which is easily maintained (no need to manually link), and a simple backup of `/opt/admin` includes all configuration. [Here's my script](https://gist.github.com/kwikwag/6320783).

Thanks Jim, for your answer.

Comment: This is more of a sysadmin question than a programming question, and probably belongs on [sf].

Answer (score 1):

I keep a parallel directory tree under my user directory

```
/home/myuserid/config/hostname/
   var
       ....
   etc
       sysconfig
           network
```

and so on.  I have a `deploy` shell script that will install files to the correct place.  I back up everything to a private externally hosted git account.

I do all editing on copies in the above parallel tree and deploy the modified files.

If you have more than a few systems to maintain this way, tools like Puppet or Chef seem to be possible options, though they come with their own headaches.  Disciplined, repeatable system administration is not trivial.

Comment: Well written. I don't like the idea of using the home directory, though -- my administrator position will go as it came, and someone else will need to know which files are where. Homedirs aren't fit for that, though a "good" admin will pass the info on.